# Sending data to server with POST through Volley not working

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Just encountered a weird problem in Volley.
First I tested the below code with Apache Http libraries, and got success, tried with a Postman Client and got success but every time in Volley I got a parsing error regarding `JsonString can't be converted to Json Object`.

This is my working code:
using old Apache HTTP LIB:

```
httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
                StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder(confirm_url);
                httpPost=new HttpPost(stringBuilder.toString());
                new webLogin().execute();
            try {
            jsonObject=new JSONObject();

            try {

                jsonObject.put("customerID",long_customerID);//long
                jsonObject.put("restaurantId",rcv_details_rcv_restaurantId);//long
                jsonObject.put("subscriptionPlan",rcv_details_subscriptionPlan);
                jsonObject.put("subscriptionDays",rcv_details_rcv_subscriptionDays);//int
                jsonObject.put("subscriptionAmount",rcv_details_subscriptionAmount);//int

                jsonObject.put("kidName",kid_name);
                jsonObject.put("clas23",rcv_class);
                jsonObject.put("section",rcv_section);
                jsonObject.put("gender",rcv_gender);
                DateTime obj=new DateTime();
                DateTime dateTime=new DateTime();
                jsonObject.put("startDate",dateTime);
                jsonObject.put("schoolName",rcv_school);
                jsonObject.put("address",rcv_delivery);

                jsonObject.put("paymentType",paymentType);
                jsonObject.put("restaurantSubscriptionId",rcv_details_rcv_restaurantSubscriptionId);//long
                jsonObject.put("subscriptionId",0);//long


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            stringEntity=new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
            httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            httpResponse=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            int statusCode=httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();


            if(statusCode==200){

                entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                System.out.println("Entity post is: "
                        + EntityUtils.toString(entity));
                mre = "200";
                Log.d("SUCCESS","YES FINALLY");
                Log.d("Ok",entity.toString());

            }else if (statusCode==412){
                Log.d("412", "412 WE MEET AGAIN)");
             mre = "412";

            }else
                Log.i("Unknown","Unknown Server Error");
            mre="unknown";

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mre;
    }
```

//working absolutely fine
This is from POSTMAN CLIENT:

[image]

//success

This is Volley (ERROR: String can't be converted to JSON Object)

```
jsonObject=new JSONObject();
    try {

        //I put it manually not through SHARED PREF

        jsonObject.put("customerID",long_customerID);//long
        jsonObject.put("restaurantId",rcv_details_rcv_restaurantId);//long
        jsonObject.put("subscriptionPlan",rcv_details_subscriptionPlan);
        jsonObject.put("subscriptionDays",rcv_details_rcv_subscriptionDays);//int
        jsonObject.put("subscriptionAmount",rcv_details_subscriptionAmount);//int


        jsonObject.put("kidName",kid_name);
        jsonObject.put("clas23",rcv_class);
        jsonObject.put("section",rcv_section);
        jsonObject.put("gender",rcv_gender);
        *//*jsonObject.put("startDate",String.valueOf(rcv_date));*//*
      *//*  DateTime obj=new DateTime();*//*
        DateTime dateTime=new DateTime();
        Log.i("ffds",dateTime.toString());

        jsonObject.put("startDate",dateTime.toString());
        jsonObject.put("schoolName",rcv_school);
        jsonObject.put("address",rcv_delivery);

        jsonObject.put("paymentType",paymentType);
        jsonObject.put("restaurantSubscriptionId",rcv_details_rcv_restaurantSubscriptionId);//long
        jsonObject.put("subscriptionId",subscriptionId);//long



        requestBody=jsonObject.toString();
        Log.i("Daa",jsonObject.toString());

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, confirm_url, requestBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response_jsonObject) {
                Log.i("Login Response",response_jsonObject.toString());

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

            }
        })
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong parameters. If you read the documentation, you'll see that you don't need to `toString` the JsonObject.

You don't really even need the Method parameter.

Try this for a POST

```
new JsonObjectRequest(confirm_url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
```

And this for a GET (the JsonObject is null because there is no body in a GET request)

```
new JsonObjectRequest(confirm_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
```

Comment: are you suggesting not to use request body sir ?

Comment: The JsonObject is the request body. It doesn't need to be a String

Comment: new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,confirm_url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()      is this correct !

Comment: Try and find out. I already gave the correct code in my answer